# [readtext]: read output from stringi replace into Quanteda

Tags: quanteda

[CODE]
DATA_DIR <- system.file("extdata/", package = "readtext")

```
x<- list.files("extdata/*", recursive = TRUE) 
library("stringi")
stri_replace_all_regex(x, "Whereas.*Whereas\n{2}", "") |>
  cat() [CODE]
```

In this example I believe all text between two instances of 'Whereas' are removed. How do I read this text, edited by stringi into Quanteda?  I want to retain the original text, but analyse the text with the selected content removed.

Answer (score 0):

That code won't work for various reasons, but let's assume that you have character vector `x` with your texts and you want to "retain the original text, but analyse the text with the selected content removed" by **stringi**.

You can use this code:

```r
# make your original text
corp <- corpus(x)

# get a tokens object for analysis
toks <- stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(x, "Whereas.*Whereas\n{2}", "") |>
  tokens()

# analyse toks here
# [code]
```

So your original object is `corp` and the subsequent analysis is on the modified object.

Comment: I can't really tell until you make answer reproducible. But that should not be happening. The readtext return is a data.frame, not a character.

Comment: My deleted comment as formatting looked wrong - Just to be clear that I'm not making a basic mistake, this is how I created x: > [CODE]  x =readtext("E:/Hanson/Data/*") [CODE]
>summary(x)  
    doc_id              text          
 Length:833         Length:833        
 Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character  If this is correct, when run the stringi code I receive a warning - "Warning message:
In stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(x, "Whereas.*Whereas\n{2}", "") :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing" . Can this warning be safely ignored?

Comment: Regarding a reproducible answer, tomorrow, Ill see if create a webpage, with all the data -i? It is 833 files, in 2 subfolders, within a folder.  I also a question about the stringi code but will add  that to the Quanteda post, after reading the data is clarified.

Comment: The files are here: http://home.brisnet.org.au/~bgreen/Data/  but as yet aren't readable, I ned to work this out:                                                                                       
  > x = readtext ("http://home.brisnet.org.au/~bgreen/Data/*")
Error in download_remote(file, ignore_missing, cache, verbosity) : 
  Remote URL does not end in known extension. Please download the file manually.

Comment: I will post a modified question, as I need to supply code to download the files.